# What is the difference between ^M$ and just $ in the end of the line in Linux

Tags: linux, special-characters, eol

In a text I have lines which end with the `^M$"` character at the end and some lines that end with just `$`. If I understand it correctly `^M` means new line and `$` just points to the end of the line. So what do `^M` and `$` together (`^M$`) mean?

Comment: A string that begins and ends with "M".

Comment: Copy some example lines that show both cases into the question.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem of [line ending](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Common_problems).

For basic texts, in Windows, conventions tell to end a line with `\r\n` characters.

In Unix world, conventions tell to end a line with a `\n` character.

The `^M` you see is just a way to display `\r` characters, which have no particuliar sense under such system.

For the `$` you see, I guess that it correspond to the `\n` character.

Comment: This answer would be improved if you touched on them being inconsistent within the same file. It sounds like the OP has mixed line ending conventions in the same file. Your answer is true, but I think it misses the point - why are there both in the same file?

Answer (score -1):

you can use dos2unix command to convert the windows specific encoding into linux format